# AngularJS $http GET: target specific input by TagName in response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've $http request for getting unique string value for token authentication. The data in response in raw html format. SO i want to get value of specific input by input-name from the response i get.

**Below is the response I'm getting on GET request.**

```
{
  "data": "<html><head><title>Login Page</title></head><body onload='document.f.username.focus();'><h3>Login with Username and Password</h3><form name='f' action='/auth/login' method='POST'><table><tr><td>User:</td><td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td></tr><tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='password'/></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/></td></tr><input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="057fe67f-c2ec-4738-a7ea-48cbfe69b2ef" /></table></form></body></html>",
  "status": 200,
  "config": {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [
        null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
        null
    ],
    "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
    "url": "http://example.com/auth/login",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
    "cached": false
  },
  "statusText": "OK",
  "xhrStatus": "complete"
}
```

In above response, I'm also getting following input with **unique value** that i want to get.

```
<input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="057fe67f-c2ec-4738-a7ea-48cbfe69b2ef" />
```

I've tried multiple approaches but couldn't get specific value of "**_csrf**" named input.

**Use Case Issue:** Another thing when i request same with POSTMAN, than it saves cookie with some information including this unqiue key. But this isn't happening on browser. If somehow i can make browser to store Cookie than that might also help.

**Here is cookie that POSTMAN is saving after request**

```
XSRF-TOKEN=057fe67f-c2ec-4738-a7ea-48cbfe69b2ef;
path=/auth;
domain=.example.com;
Expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT;
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: above response seems to be like redirection to login page

Comment: This request is initiating on load when user lands on login page. Than this unique value will be pass along with login request in order to get authenticated token.

Comment: @georgeBailey, yes the reqest response also returning login form markup which i dont want to proceed with. I just want unique value from input.